# Filing state taxes as a student

Tags: student

My resident state is NJ. I attended college in Georgia and my grandparents cashed in a 529 Plan to pay my tuition in Georgia. I then transferred to a college in Colorado during that same (tax) year. They used some of that same 529 Fund money for my tuition in Colorado. Both Georgia and Colorado are wanting me to pay state taxes for the monies of the 529 Plan. Which state(s) do I file?

Comment: You probably file as a part year resident in all the states you resided in for part of the year. But of course it depends on the specific rules for each state.

Comment: Did the 529 money pass the federal test for qualified use? Did the money go from 529-to-school, or 529-to-you-to-school, or 529-to-grandpartensts-to-school?